# Join grouping by periods, full join not working as intended

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sales table:

```
SALES
|---------|-------------|-------------|
|  order  |   ammount   |  date       |
|---------|-------------|-------------|
|  001    | $2,000      | 2018-01-01  |
|  002    | $3,000      | 2018-01-01  |
|  003    | $1,500      | 2018-01-03  |
|  004    | $1,700      | 2018-01-04  |
|  005    | $1,800      | 2018-01-09  |
|  006    | $4,200      | 2018-01-11  |
|---------|-------------|-------------|
```

Aditionally, I have a table that groups said sales according to arbitrary time periods:

```
BUDGET PERIODS
|---------|-------------|--------------|
| ID      | start_date  | end_date     |
|---------|-------------|--------------|
| 1       | 2018-01-01  | 2018-01-02   | <- notice this is a 2 day period...
| 2       | 2018-01-03  | 2018-01-05   | <-- but this is 3 days
|---------|-------------|--------------|
```

So, my result table query looked like this:

```
GROUPED SALES
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| start_date   | end_date      | ammount         |
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-02    | $5,000          |
| 2018-01-03   | 2018-01-05    | $3,200          |
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
```

I accomplished it by a query as such:

```
SELECT
    bp.start_date,
    bp.end_date,
    SUM(s.ammount)
FROM
    budget_periods bp
LEFT JOIN 
    sales s ON s.date >= bp.start_date AND s.date <= bp.end_date
GROUP BY 
    start_date, 
    end_date
```

Everything is awesome, then. BUT, I notice that, of course, some sales are not included because they're not in budget periods. Hence, I want to include them "somewhere". I decided that that "somewhere" would be the week of the sale (using the week truncate function in Postgres). Hence, my grouped sales should look like this now:

```
GROUPED SALES
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| start_date   | end_date      | ammount         |
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
| 2018-01-01   | 2018-01-02    | $5,000          |
| 2018-01-03   | 2018-01-05    | $3,200          |
| 2018-01-08   | 2018-01-14    | $6,000          |
|--------------|---------------|-----------------|
```

Notice that if you truncate-to-week both 2018-01-09 and 2018-01-11, it shows 2018-01-08. To calculate my end_date, the budget period is "defaulted" to seven days, so it's six days later than the start_date.

So, I modified the query into a FULL JOIN like this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(bp.start_date, DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', s.date)) AS new_start_date,
    COALESCE(bp.end_date, DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', s.date) + INTERVAL '6 DAY') AS new_end_date,
    SUM(s.ammount)
FROM
    budget_periods bp
FULL JOIN 
    sales s ON s.date >= bp.start_date AND s.date <= bp.end_date
GROUP BY 
    new_start_date, 
    new_end_date
```

But then, the result table is the same as when I had a LEFT JOIN. How should I approach this?

Thank you for your time in reading such a long time to explain issue.

Comment: BTW it would be nice if you provide working example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=76cb1e05f884bcc48eb14e48c6d0d300

Comment: And changing `FULL JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN` gives the expected result: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cd71bdb7efe28e9c7d473ebf86aa3f10

Comment: @Abelisto. How clever. What amazes me is that that `WITH` statement solves the problem with a `RIGHT JOIN`, yet that is not the case with tables already stored in the database. It also disallows the use of the `FULL JOIN` with an error I had not encountered before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all rows in *sales* then make that the first table in a `LEFT JOIN`.  However, I think the `FULL JOIN` should work, as should this `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(bp.start_date, DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', s.date)) as new_start_date,
       COALESCE(bp.end_date, DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', s.date) + interval '6 day') as new_end_date,
       SUM(s.amount)
FROM sales s LEFT JOIN
     budget_periods bp
     ON s.date >= bp.start_date AND s.date <= bp.end_date
GROUP BY new_start_date, new_end_date;
```

The only reason things would be filtered out of the `FULL JOIN` is through a `WHERE` clause, but you don't have one.

Comment: I do have a WHERE clause, however. I left it out of the question to reduce complexity. I just assumed it wasn't relevant. In a closer version to reality, my sales table has another column that show 'store', and I only need to include certain stores, so my queries have a `WHERE s.store IN ('store1', 'store2')` but checking the data, this store-excluding filter isn't the reason my other sales don't appear, since the filter doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @JDGamboa . . . The filter has everything to do with the behavior you are seeing.  Ask another question.